# Présentation de condoléance

Tags: usage, formulation

J'aimerais savoir les formules usitées s'il y a lieu de différencier géographiquement:

- en France métropolitaine en l'occurrence
- en Belgique francophone
- en Suisse
- au Canada francophone
- ...

Comment: Pour les ... : n'oubliez pas l'Afrique où il y a le plus de francophones que partout ailleurs, et les îles où les expressions locales peuvent être savoureuses.

Comment: @cl-r: Vous avez raison, étant moi même Africain et insulaire!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La formule classique que j'utilise (France) : *Veuillez accepter mes sincères condoléances*.

Note : Les sites de pompes funèbres proposent des formules « toutes faites » adaptées en fonction de la proximité qu'on avait avec le défunt.